# TypeError: serialport.parsers.readline is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to run this program in Raspberry Pi 3.
I have installed nodejs and ws on my raspberry pi.
Then I installed serial port module.
I am trying to create this project:[enter link description here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Smart-Pantry/) 
I have tried to find solutions everywhere but I could not find one.
If any one knows how to solve this problem please help me.

```js
var webSocketUrl = "wss://api.artik.cloud/v1.1/websocket?ack=true";
var device_id = "5bb3ba9304674086bee67fa507a215cf"; //DEVICE ID
var device_token = "36b278345b6d4d11abf764ae213c5c70"; //DEVICE TOKEN

var WebSocket = require('ws');
var isWebSocketReady = false;
var data="";
var ws = null;
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
var sp = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0", { //for serial communication with arduino 
    baudrate: 9600,  
// The baud rate of uno is 9600
    parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
});


/**
 * Gets the current time in millis
 */
function getTimeMillis(){
    return parseInt(Date.now().toString());
}

/**
 * Create a /websocket connection and setup GPIO pin
 */
function start() {
    //Create the WebSocket connection
    isWebSocketReady = false;
    ws = new WebSocket(webSocketUrl);
    ws.on('open', function() {
        console.log("WebSocket connection is open ....");
        register();
    });
    ws.on('message', function(data) {
      //this loop is called whenever the client sends some message
         handleRcvMsg(data); //data is send to the function handleRcvMsg()
    });
    ws.on('close', function() {
        console.log("WebSocket connection is closed ....");

    });

   
      
    
}

/**
 * Sends a register message to /websocket endpoint
 */
//Client will only work when device gets registered from here
function register(){
    console.log("Registering device on the WebSocket connection");
    try{
        var registerMessage = '{"type":"register", "sdid":"'+device_id+'", "Authorization":"bearer '+device_token+'", "cid":"'+getTimeMillis()+'"}';
        console.log('Sending register message ' + registerMessage + '\n');
        ws.send(registerMessage, {mask: true});
        isWebSocketReady = true;
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error('Failed to register messages. Error in registering message: ' + e.toString());
    }    
}


//data after receiving is sent here for processing
function handleRcvMsg(msg){
    var msgObj = JSON.parse(msg);
    if (msgObj.type != "action") return; //Early return;

    var actions = msgObj.data.actions;
    var actionName = actions[0].name; //assume that there is only one action in actions
    console.log("The received action is " + actionName);
   
}



/**
 * Send one message to ARTIK Cloud
 */
//This function is responsible for sending commands to cloud
//function sendStateToArtikCloud(parking,temperature,water){
function sendDataToArtikCloud(pantry){
 var result=pantry.split(" ");//data gets split by " " to get the values
    try{
        ts = ', "ts": '+getTimeMillis();
        var data = {
            "Garlic": result[1],
            "Potato":result[2],
            "Temperature":result[3],
            "Chilli":result[4],
            "Humidity": result[5],
   "Ginger":result[6],
            "Onion": result[7]
            };
        var payload = '{"sdid":"'+device_id+'"'+ts+', "data": '+JSON.stringify(data)+', "cid":"'+getTimeMillis()+'"}';
        console.log('Sending payload ' + payload + '\n');
        ws.send(payload, {mask: true});
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error in sending a message: ' + e.toString() +'\n');
    }    
}



function exitClosePins() {
    
        console.log('Exit and destroy all pins!');
        process.exit();
    
}


start();
//exectes every second when data is received from arduino (5sec programmed delay from arduino)
sp.on("open", function () {
    sp.on('data', function(data) {

            console.log("Serial port received data:" + data);
            //var result=data.split(" ");//data gets split by " " to get the values
            //sendStateToArtikCloud(result[0],result[2],result[1]);//parking,temperature,waterlevel
            sendDataToArtikCloud(data);
           
    });
});


process.on('SIGINT', exitClosePins);
```

I am getting an error on my raspberry pi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FBrI.png)

Suggest me a solution.

Comment: You would need to check the `serialport` module for reference to the requested function (`serialport.parsers.readline()`).

Answer (score 1):

[TypeError: serialport.parsers.readline is not a function.]

If it has not been resolved yet, try this method.

```
var serialport = require("serialport")
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
var sp = new serialport("/dev/ttyACM0"),{
  BaudRate: 9600,
  parser: new serialport.parsers.Readline("\r\n")
});
```

I hope your problem is solved.

Comment: This is why, we should not give up on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation will tell you that `Readline` is spelled with a capital `R`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport#module_serialport--SerialPort.parsers

```
parser: serialport.parsers.Readline("\n")
                           ~
```

Comment: parser: serialport.parsers.Readline("\n")
                               ^

TypeError: Class constructor ReadLineParser cannot be invoked without 'new'                                                                                                                                                   I am getting an error like this if I use Readline.